# compare boxplots with a single value

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, facet

I want to compare the distribution of several variables (here `X1` and `X2`) with a single value (here `bm`). The issue is that these variables are too many (about a dozen) to use a single boxplot. [image]

Additionaly the levels are too different to use one plot. I need to use facets to make things more organised: [image]

However with this plot my benchmark category (`bm`), which is a single value in `X1` and `X2`, does not appear in `X1` and seems to have several values in `X2`. I want it to be only this green line, which it is in the first plot. Any ideas why it changes? Is there any good workaround? I tried the options of `facet_wrap`/`facet_grid`, but nothing there delivered the right result.

I also tried combining a bar plot with `bm` and three empty categories with the boxplot. But firstly it looked terrible and secondly it got similarly screwed up in the facetting. Basically any work around would help.

Below the code to create the minimal example displayed here:

```
# Creating some sample data & loading libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
set.seed(10111)
x=matrix(rnorm(40),20,2)
y=rep(c(-1,1),c(10,10))
x[y==1,]=x[y==1,]+1
x[,2]=x[,2]+20
df=data.frame(x,y)

# creating a benchmark point
benchmark=data.frame(y=rep("bm",2),key=c("X1","X2"),value=c(-0.216936,20.526312))
# melting the data frame, rbinding it with the benchmark
test_dat=rbind(tidyr::gather(df,key,value,-y),benchmark)

# Creating a plot
p_box <- ggplot(data = test_dat, aes(x=key, y=value,color=as.factor(test_dat$y))) +
    geom_boxplot() +  scale_color_manual(name="Cluster",values=brewer.pal(8,"Set1"))

# The first line delivers the first plot, the second line the second plot
p_box
p_box + facet_wrap(~key,scales = "free",drop = FALSE) + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Comment: _"gets messed up"_: please be explicit about what you don't like, and what you want instead. Also, the readability of your code would really be helped by consistent spacing.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question. Will edit the code too now. Though I am not sure what you mean with consistent spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem only lies int the use of `test_dat$y` inside the color `aes`. Never use `$` in `aes`, ggplot will mess up.

Anyway, I think you plot would improve if you use a `geom_hline` for the benchmark, instead of hacking in a single value boxplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

ggplot(tidyr::gather(df,key,value,-y)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(x=key, y=value, color=as.factor(y))) +
    geom_hline(data = benchmark, aes(yintercept = value), color = '#4DAF4A', size = 1) +
    scale_color_manual(name="Cluster",values=brewer.pal(8,"Set1")) +
    facet_wrap(~key,scales = "free",drop = FALSE) + 
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot. Didnt even know `geom_hline`. Basically saving a line of code got me into trouble. 

Note for other people who have a similar issues with `facet`: 
Using `test_dat[,"y"]` also messes up the facets and likely `ggplot` too if I understand @GGamba right.

Comment: ggplot uses something called ['non standard evaluation'](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) where it would 'automagically' interpret arguments as column names  insted of standalone objects (that's a simplification ofc). Deviation from this norm causes troubles